# Remove IBOutlet programmatically that is set in interface builder and add it again with same constraints

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, iboutlet

Lets say I have a ViewController in a .nib file with an IBOutlet imageView as subView with constraints, the imageView is connected to the ViewController class associated with the nib file. Now I remove the imageView with the following code:

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

And later I want to add it again to the ViewController View with the same constraints as I set in the interface builder before I removed the imageView. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do that in code without initialising the ViewController again?
2. If I add the imageView as SubView to the VC programmatically after I have removed it the constraints are no longer available. I would really like to skip setting the constraints again in code since they already exist in the interface builder, is that possible?

Comment: It may be easier to hide/show your image view and adjust other constraints as needed rather than removing it.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just hide the image view like this:

```
imageView.isHidden = true
```

or

```
imageView.alpha = 0
```

Otherwise, you can store the constraints somewhere and add it back to the appropriate views later.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to save your constraints in a var and set them back programatically. By the way since IBOutlet is weak, once you remove it you can't add the imageView back. So you'll have to maintain a strong reference. Also removing the imageView will disturb other views that have dependent constraints. However if other views' constraints are independent of your imageView it won't be a problem.

The other way is have a reference to your imageView's height or width constraint and change its constant to zero to virtually make it disappear from your view. This way you'll just have to change the constraint back to its original value to unhide it and also makes sure that other views' constraints get adjusted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically, in your view controller, save the constraints before removing the image view, like so:

```
let savedConstraints = view.constraints.filter { (constraint) -> Bool in
    constraint.firstItem as? UIView == myImageView || constraint.secondItem as? UIImageView == myImageView
}
```

... where `myImageView` is the image view you're going to remove. The above checks reads the constraints connected to your view and returns the ones that are connected to your image view.

Then you could re-add these constraints when creating a new image view:

```
let myNewImageView = UIImageView()
view.addSubview(myNewImageView)
savedConstraints.forEach { (constraint) in
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: view,
            attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
            relatedBy: constraint.relation,
            toItem: myNewImageView,
            attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
            multiplier: constraint.multiplier,
            constant: constraint.constant))
}
```

Although I agree with the commenters who recommended just hiding the image view.